# Why would an APL implementation include "Deep Transpose"?

Tags: language-design, apl

[APL64 includes a `⎕DTR` system function](http://apl2000.com/APL64/UserDocumentation/APL64_SYSTEM_FUNCTION.pdf#page=52) which, as far as I can tell, is equivalent to `⍉¨⍉` i.e. the transposed outer array with each element also being transposed.*

What is the use case for such a built-in, and why not just use the primitives? A possible answer could for example be that computation of the final result can be optimised more than doing separate transposes.

---

<sup>* Note that the documentation says the "result is an array with the same rank and shape", but this is clearly contradicted by the shown example, and thus appears to be a mistake.</sup>

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: To me it seems more like `{IsSimple ⍵: ⍉⍵ ⋄ ⍉∇¨⍵}`.

Comment: @Bubbler Ah, that could be, and since APL64 doesn't have dfns, it'd be slightly more awkward to write that. (Btw, `IsSimple` is `1≥≡`)

Comment: I found a [changelist](http://www.lescasse.com/Content/NewAplwinFeatures.aspx) entry saying 'This System Function is very useful when passing arrays to an ActiveX method as arrays needs to be deeply transposed in that case.'  Not very illuminating, but seems worth mentioning.